# Why does reading /proc/net/tcp take a long time ss is quick to return the same sort of data about the connections table?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, kernel, proc

On Linux 2.6.32, if you read (for example, cat) /proc/net/tcp, on a very loaded system (for example, a web server), you will find that reading 100K entries takes over 30 seconds.  That's a long time.

What's going on behind the scenes?  Is there locking going on?

Many people mention the speed of the 'ss' command.  What is the 'ss' command doing that 'cat /proc/net/tcp' or 'netstat' isn't doing that makes it so much faster?

Answer (score 4):

`ss` uses the `AF_NETLINK` socket layer to talk to the kernel.  This is a lower level protocol but allows for data to be transferred very quickly and in large chunks.  A quick `strace` on CentOS 7 shows it sets the transfer window to be 1Mb.